# kth order statistic in range [i, j]

Tags: algorithm, sorting

There is a problem but I can't find a efficient algorithm for it.

### Problem

Given an array of numbers `a[1], ..., a[n]`, we get queries of the kind:

- `SELECT(i, j, k)`: find k-th smallest number in range [i, j] after sorting `a[i], a[i+1], ..., a[j]`
- `SET(i, value)`: perform `a[i] = value`

### Example

Input:

```
5 5 // n = 5 (size of array), m = 5 (number of query)
5 10 9 6 7
select 2 4 1
select 2 4 2
set 3 12
set 4 15
select 2 4 1
```

Output:

```
6
9
10
```

I think that we can implement this with `Merge Sort Tree` (`Special segment tree`). I found this in internet: [merge sort tree for range order statistics](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-tree-for-range-order-statistics/)

but because we can change array value, this algorithm in not efficient.
Is it possible to help me, How can I implement it efficiently?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you complexity constrains? Does `O(nlogn)` for each query is good? `O(n)`? Can pre-processing in `nlogn` allowed?

Comment: `O(nlogn)` is good but you can do any pre-processing.

Comment: Why not update the merge sort tree?

Comment: become complexity of that is not good. I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the merge-sort-tree but I can think of different data-structure / algorithm that gives you the desire output in `O(n)` per query.

Notice solution for this problem depends on the **distribution** between `SET` and `SELECT` queries -> I assume there are more `SELECT`'s so I tried to lower that complexity. If you have more `SET`'s then I would use @miradham answer:

```
        david    miradham 
SET      O(n)      O(1)
SELECT   O(n)      O(nlogn)
Space    O(n)      O(n)
```

Both solution are space complexity of `O(n)`.

In your question you used indexes that start from 1 -> I will modify it to start from 0.

Let look at your example: `a = array (5, 10, 9, 6, 7)`. As pre-processing we will create sorted array that contains also the original index of the elements -> `b = array(5(0), 6(3), 7(4), 9(2), 10(1))` when the number in bracket is the index in the original array `a`. This can be done in `O(nlogn)`.

How do we deals with the queries?

**SELECT(i, j, k)**:

```
let cnt = 1;
for m in b (sorted array)
    if m(index) <= i && m(index) <= j // the index is in given range
        if (cnt == k)
            return k // found the k lowest
        else cnt++
```

This is `O(n)` as you loop over `b`

**SET(i, value)**:

Changing `a` is easy and can be done in `O(1)`. Changing `b`:

```
originalValue = a[i] // old value
Add [value(i)] to b as new element // O(logn) as b sorted
Remove [originalValue(i)] from b // b sorted but array implementation may cause O(n)
```

Total of `O(n)`

If further explanation is needed feel free to ask. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. it is good. I ask another question. is it possible to implemet it with sqrt decomposition?

Comment: I don't think so. because which value you assign to each block?

Comment: I don't know. someone just say this to me but I couldn't find anything. I just ask here. I think that is not possible too.